# NSMenuItem action not invoked

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsmenuitem

The title says it all: The action `objcDeleteCurrentSelection` of the NSMenuItem won't be invoked on click or key equivalent. Item and function are part of a NSMenu used as application window menu.

I've tried to set the target, both to nil and to self (the NSMenu which declares the function). I've also tried to use params such as Any or AnyObject. The NSMenuItem gets correctly enabled or disabled.

FYI: The implementation of `objcDeleteCurrentSelection` invokes a Swift protocol extension function.

````
class OptionsMenu : NSMenu, NSMenuDelegate, OptionsControllerDelegate {

    private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private var deleteItem: NSMenuItem? = nil

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        item(withTitle: "Edit")?.isEnabled = true
        deleteItem = item(withTitle: "Edit")?.submenu?.item(withTitle: "Delete")
        deleteItem?.action = #selector(objcDeleteCurrentSelection)
        delegate = self
        self.onSelectionChange.subscribe { [weak self] in
            guard let it = $0.element else { return }
            let enableDelete = !it.0.isEmpty || !it.1.isEmpty
            self?.deleteItem?.isEnabled = enableDelete
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    @objc func objcDeleteCurrentSelection() {
        deleteCurrentSelection()
    }

}
```
````

Comment: This is really poor MVC design. Unless you have a *very* good reason, you don't subclass view/control classes (like `NSMenu`) to add functionality. You connect them (via `delegate`, `action`, and `target`) to controller objects which performs those task. The reason setting `self.target=nil` doesn't work is because menu items aren't part of the the responder chain. No idea why setting it to `self` doesn't work, other than menu items were never designed to be used that way. Consider creating a "command" object to perform the work indeed.

Comment: I don't strictly follow patterns if they just complicate things. When the amount of LOC grows, I'll do some refactoring to keep things clean :)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know: You were right. Self as a target somehow does not work.